# XMLHttpRequest POST redirects before I get the response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Javascript:

```
function basiclogin() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "login");
  xhttp.send(new FormData(document.forms.login));
  xhttp.onload = () => alert(xhttp.response);
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
...
<script>basiclogin()</script>
</html>
```

This works and gives an alert from the server.
But if I call basiclogin() using a submit buttom in the form the page redirects and shows the response as a new document before I recieve the response!

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of a submit button is to open the page to send the data to the server. If you wish to prevent this, you need to use `event.preventDefault()`.

E.g.

```
function basiclogin(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "login");
  xhttp.send(new FormData(document.forms.login));
  xhttp.onload = () => alert(xhttp.response);
}
```

Then add the parameter to the submit button onClick handler.

E.g. something like:

`submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => basicLogin(event))`

Comment: Yes I forgot to add type="button". I had no type which is submit apparantly